# F#: How to print a custom class?

Tags: f#

I'm trying to teach myself F#. I've set up a simple class and would like to be able to print it.

Is there an idiomatic equivalent to C++'s overloading of `operator<<(std::ostream&,const MyClass&)` that would allow me to print with, for instance, `printfn`? If not what is the "standard" way of custom classes?

For concreteness here is the class as it currently stands

```
type Vect(x: float, y: float) = 
    new() = Vect(0.,0.)
    member this.x = x
    member this.y = y
    static member (-) (v1: Vect, v2: Vect) = 
        Vect(v1.x-v2.x,v1.y-v2.y)
    member this.Magnitude() = 
        sqrt(x**2. + y**2.)
```

Comment: Have you looked at overriding `ToString()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard way is to override `x.ToString()` like so

```
override this.ToString() = sprintf "%f,%f" x y
```

You can then print this with

```
printf "%O" Some_Vect
```

Comment: Perfect thanks, I thought `ToString` would enter somewhere but I couldn't find the answer on Google.

Answer (score 8):

The [`StructuredFormatDisplay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370334.aspx) attribute can also be used.

```
[<StructuredFormatDisplay("Name: {FullName}")>]
type Person(first, last) =
  member val First = first
  member val Last = last
  member this.FullName = first + " " + last
  override this.ToString() = last + ", " + first

let person = Person("John", "Doe")
printfn "%O" person
> Doe, John
printfn "%A" person
> Name: John Doe
```